# Problem Uploading a file via FTP using FtpWebRequest when the file does not already exist on FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

This seems like a trivial problem, but my web searches for an answer (even on this site) have forced me to ask the question explicitly.

I am uploading a file via FTP from my server to a remote server.  My code looks like this...

```
public void Upload(string fileToUpload)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.remoteserver.com/Data/" + fileToUpload);
        request.UsePassive = false;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username","password");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileToUpload);
        byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
    }
```

This all seems very straight-forward.  The problem I am having is that I get a 550 error when the file does not already exist on the remote server.  I would assume that if the file doe snot exist, then the file would be created.  Further, I assume that if it does that it will be overwritten.

Since this is not the case (at least with writing a new file), I would further assume that I should (a) somehow check for the file first, and (b) create it if it does not exist.  But how to do this?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Have you checked that the account has permission to create files on the FTP server?

Comment: What are you passing into `fileToUpload`, an absolute file path such as `c:\File.txt` or just a filename like `File.txt`? Also, do you understand that your program only works with text files, right?

Comment: @JNappi: it's not a permissions issue, as the FTP credentials are for a user with write permissions (I control both servers, and so can confirm this).

Comment: @Chris Haas: I am passing "File.txt," and I am aware that this only works with text files.

Comment: @Chris Haas:  Arrg!  I just checked and the fileToUpload is the full path to the local file!  Good catch (and what an idiot I am!).

Can you add an "answer" so I can give you credit?

Comment: @mikerennick, I converted my comment to an answer, glad you were able to work it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(comment converted to answer)

What are you passing into `fileToUpload`, an absolute file path such as `c:\File.txt` or just a filename like `File.txt`? Also, do you understand that your program only works with text files, right?

Comment: Thanks...cannot believe that I came on here to debug a parameter :)...but much appreciated nonetheless.